# Can rosbridge set the timestamp of stamped messages?

Tags: ros, messages, timestamp, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

I am using [rosbridge](http://ros.org/wiki/rosbridge) in my project and it would be great if the bridge could set the timestamps in messages passed through it as simple json messages. Is that supported somehow?

Cheers,
J.B.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29851/can-rosbridge-set-the-timestamp-of-stamped-messages?/) by [JBuesch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1539/jbuesch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 237 on 2012-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the current SVN (experimental version of rosbridge):

```
svn co http://brown-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/experimental/rosbridge
```

I have added a feature so that if you send a header (or an object containing a header) with an empty stamp field, it will be replaced with the current rostime. In other words:

```
con.publish('/heads','std_msgs/Header',{seq:42,frame_id:'foo',stamp:{}})
```

results in something like:

```
seq: 43                                                                                             
stamp:                                                                                              
  secs: 1332141768                                                                                  
  nsecs: 325777053                                                                                  
frame_id: foo
```

Keep in mind that this is purely for cases where you don't need a very accurate timestamp. The *proper* thing to do is still to synchronize the client and ROS runtime's clocks.

If for some reason you don't want to run the SVN version of rosbridge, you can also use [this](http://pastebin.com/pRKtK9hg) patch until the binary version is updated (after more time and testing).

---

Originally posted by [tjay](https://answers.ros.org/users/502/tjay/) with karma: 461 on 2012-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1